# Display author meta on WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I am using the WooCommerce product Vendor plugin on my WordPress site. Each vendor got their own vendor profile. I want to display author meta such as LinkedIn, facebook, wikipedia etc. on each vendor product.

The social profiles data is stored in the regular WordPress user profile. If you create a new user on a WP installation you should see facebook profile URL, Wikipedia, LinkedIn etc. under the contact information form table. Each user therefore just enter their social profiles within their WordPress profile.

I am new to PHP so probally a pretty basic question. I tried to make my code work by a lot of trail & error. However, I am running into a dead-end in my code when I try to get user id from the title.

If I do var_dump( $vendor_data ); I get all of the user information I need:

```
array(1) { [63]=> array(21) { ["notes"]=> string(0) "" ["logo"]=> string(0) "" ["profile"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["admins"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(20) } ["commission"]=> int(70) ["commission_type"]=> string(10) "percentage" ["paypal"]=> string(0) "" ["timezone"]=> string(5) "UTC+2" ["enable_bookings"]=> string(2) "no" ["per_product_shipping"]=> string(2) "no" ["instant_payout"]=> string(2) "no" ["term_id"]=> int(63) ["name"]=> string(9) "Tobias M." ["slug"]=> string(8) "tobias-m" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(63) ["taxonomy"]=> string(20) "wcpv_product_vendors" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(2) } }
```

With the var_dump above I've changed line 11 to be:

```
$vendor_data[ $vendor_id ] = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_data_by_id( $vendor_id )->name;`
```

After doing some research I found that -> is not valid because -> means I am accessing an object, but in my case, I need to retrieve data from array. Therefore I tried something like this but still no luck:

```
// get vendor data
$vendor_data = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_data_by_id( $vendor_id['name'] );
$name = $vendor_data['name'];
```

**MY CODE:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'our_vendor_info' );
function our_vendor_info() {
    if( is_product() ) {
        // get the product id of the order item
                $product_id = get_queried_object()->ID;

                // get vendor id from product id
                $vendor_id = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_id_from_product( $product_id );

                // get vendor data
                $vendor_data[ $vendor_id ] = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_data_by_id( $vendor_id )->name;

        var_dump( $vendor_data );

        // Now get user id from title
        $user = get_userdatabylogin($vendor_data);

                      // Get social profiles
              $wikipedia = get_the_author_meta( 'wikipedia', $user->ID );   

        echo '<div class="large-3 columns venprofilelink">';
        if (get_the_author_meta( 'wikipedia', $user->ID )) {
            echo '<span class="some-talent"><a href="'. $wikipedia .'" target="blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="http://example.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/wikipedia-logo.svg" /></a></span>';
        } else {
            echo 'Hello World!';
            }
        }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the meta-key "wikipedia" exists in the database?

Comment: I am not really that experienced in database. However, I did take a look and in wp_usermeta There is a column called meta_key where all the social media profiles is listed: facebook, instagram, linkedin, myspace, pinterest, soundcloud, tumblr, twitter, youtube & wikipedia. The profile links is then stored in meta_values.

It's regular WP user metadata. If you create a new user on a fresh WordPress installation  you should be able to see social profiles under the contact information form table.

Comment: The entry won't be created in the database unless a value is set for it, but I'll assume the value for some or all of the users you expect to show it has been set. Normally,I'd want to check to see that every necessary and expected value/condition is being found/satisfied. So, to start with, are you getting "Hello World!" on the front end? If not then it suggests is_tax( 'shop_vendor' ) is false or maybe the 'product_vendors_tab_content_before' action isn't working as expected.

Comment: Yes, the value for some users has been filled in and stored in the database. No, I am not getting Hello World. I tried to change shop_vendor to product_cat but that didn't do any difference... I changed before tab content to woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button that did something - My layout got all screwed up but still nothing being outputted :/

Comment: is_tax( 'shop_vendor' ) is definitely false. I took the if statement from the blog post I am linking in question. I see he is using that for placing upload field in the backend of shop vendor... I only need to output in front end and not shop vendor backend...

Comment: well... that might also explain why your layout got screwed up when you apply it to a working action, since the way the code is written an isolated "</div>" gets echoed out if is_tax is false... Otherwise, it looks you've got either a lot of trial and error or research ahead of you - unless you need this solved quickly, in which case you may need to hire a developer.

Comment: @CKMacLeod thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I went with research and some trial&error. I have updated code in question with my finding. My problem atm. is, that if I do var_dump( $vendor_data ); I get pretty much all of the user information I need:  ["name"]=> string(9) "Tobias M." ["slug"]=> string(8) "tobias-m". This is why I did ->name to fetch user name and then get user id from name... But I kinda run into dead-end there. Dunno if I am writing ->name wrong or something.

Comment: Maybe update your question with the code you're now using and the var_dump? The answer could be obvious (use array syntax?), but might as well give me or someone a chance to write out the answer if you don't already have it by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the WooCommerce Vendors plugin, so I haven't tested this code. More specifically, it looks like `$vendor_id` may just be a regular User ID associated with a Vendor. If that's the case, then the sub-routine for getting the User ID would be unnecessary, but, just in case that's wrong, I'll include a second version of the code that includes it. I'm also re-writing it to avoid outputting an empty div if there's nothing to go inside it.

Also, `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` is a hook that appears in `single-product` templates, so you shouldn't need to test whether you're displaying a product  with `is_product()`.

```
/**
 * Output a Wikipedia image-link for a a Woocommerce Vendor
 * If $vendor_id is equal to $user_id
 **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'our_vendor_info' );

function our_vendor_info() {

    // get vendor id from product id
    $vendor_id = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_id_from_product( get_the_ID() );

    if ( $vendor_id && get_the_author_meta( 'wikipedia', $vendor_id ) ) {

        // Get Wikipedia profile
        $wikipedia = get_the_author_meta( 'wikipedia', $vendor_id );   

        echo '<div class="large-3 columns venprofilelink">';

        echo '<span class="some-talent">
            <a href="'. $wikipedia .'" target="blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/wikipedia-logo.svg" />
            </a>
         </span>'; 

        echo '</div>';

    }

}
```

If that's not the case, and `$vendor_id` really is a unique ID number, meaning the coders who associated it with specific User IDs didn't bother to include the latter in the $vendor_id data or any of their utility functions or filters or actions, then you'll need something a little more complicated, like what you or that other coder wrote:

```
/**
 * If $vendor_id is *not* equal to $user_id
 **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'our_vendor_info' );

function our_vendor_info() {

    // get vendor id from product id
    $vendor_id = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_id_from_product( get_the_ID() );

    //if there's no vendor_id then nothing to do here
    if ( $vendor_id ) {

        // get vendor data so we can get User ID
        $vendor_data = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_vendor_data_by_id( $vendor_id ); 

        //get_userdatabylogin() is deprecated, also $vendor_data does not include a "login," but does include a slug
        //(which should be reliable)
        $user_id = get_user_by( 'slug', $vendor_data['slug'] )->ID ; 

        //don't output anything unless there's a reason to do it
        if ( get_the_author_meta( 'wikipedia', $user_id ) ) {

            // Get Wikipedia profile url
            $wikipedia = get_the_author_meta( 'wikipedia', $user_id );   

            echo '<div class="large-3 columns venprofilelink">';

            echo '<span class="some-talent">
                <a href="'. $wikipedia .'" target="blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/wikipedia-logo.svg" />
                </a>
             </span>'; 

            echo '</div>';

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The second solution with $vendor_id being a unique ID did the trick. Thank you so much! I am really a php newbie but learned so much in this process... You have been really helpful with pointing me in the right direction. Much appreciated!